# The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am doing Chapter 7 of Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and I am getting errors when trying to sign up a user in development.  I have finished the chapter through 7.3 so all of my tests should be passing now, but I'm still receiving `The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController` in development.

Here is my Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
    end     
end
```

At this point in the tutorial I should be able to sign a user up in the online form without issue.  Here is my github repository https://github.com/ajhausdorf/sample_app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `def new` has not been closed.

This code should works

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end # Here what you missing

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `end`s are out of whack:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end # You were missing one here.

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
    # end # You have an extra one here.
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `new` method doesn't end where you think it ends; it encompasses both the `create` and `user_params` methods.

You've created a local method called `create` **inside** the `new` method, rather than creating a regular instance method called `create` on the `UserController` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end  # you are missing this line

def create
```